Is it valid to replace the limit of a function inside the indifnite integration when computing limits?
The original problem tells me that

$f(x)$ is continuous on $[0, +\infty)$
$f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote $y=b\ne 0$, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=b \ne 0
$$

Then it asks me to choice one correct option from

When $a > 0$,  any solution to $y' + ay = f(x)$ satifies $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x)={b \over a}$
When $a > 0$,  any solution to $y' + ay = f(x)$ satifies $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x)={a \over b}$
When $a < 0$,  any solution to $y' + ay = f(x)$ satifies $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x)={b \over a}$
When $a < 0$,  any solution to $y' + ay = f(x)$ satifies $\lim_{x \to +\infty} y(x)={a \over b}$

I "solved" the problem like this:
First solve for $y$,
$$
y=e^{-ax}\left(\int f(x)e^{ax}dx+C\right)
$$
where $C$ is any constant.
Then take limit from both side,
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{-ax}\left(\int f(x)e^{ax}dx+C\right)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{-ax}\left(\int be^{ax}dx+C\right)
$$
Now the integral of the rightmost side of the above equation is easily solveable. Hence the correct option is option 1.
My concern is that it is not allowed to replace $f(x)$ by its limit when $f(x)$ is inside an integral operator, I've never did that before, is it possible? If so when it is possible?

Here is one way to solve the multiple-choice question.
You may not manipulate the limit in such a manner since you are passing it over terms which depend on $x$.
Once you have the explicit form however, since $f\to0$, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can split the integral $\int_0^x f(s)e^{as}\,ds$ at an $x_0$ such that $f(x) \le b+\varepsilon$ for $x \ge x_0$, in order to obtain
$$ \int_0^x f(s)e^{as}\,ds = \int_0^{x_0} + \int_{x_0}^x \le C_\varepsilon + \frac{b+\varepsilon}ae^{ax} \text, \quad x\ge x_0 \text. $$
Inserting back into the general solution gives
$$ y \le \frac{b+\varepsilon}a + e^{-ax}(C_\varepsilon+C) \text, \quad x \ge x_0 \text. $$
If $a>0$, then $\limsup_{x\to+\infty} y \le (b+\varepsilon)/a$ since $e^{-ax}\to0$.
This can be done for any $\varepsilon>0$, and can also be repeated to bound below with $\liminf_{x\to+\infty}y \ge (b-\varepsilon)/a$.
This proves, under the condition that $a>0$, that $\lim_{x\to+\infty} y = b/a$.
Taking $f$ to be constant eliminates the other answers; in fact this is another way to choose the correct answer, though arguably less pedagogical.
